# ruby -e fails handling white spaces

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run ruby from the command line but I'm finding that it struggles with the white spaces:

This code will print both entries:

```
$ ruby -e "puts('something');puts('again')"
something
again
```

This code will only print one:

```
$ ruby -e "puts('something'); puts('again')"
something
```

The reason why I'm using parenthesis is because it won't accept parameters without them:

```
$ ruby -e "require 'json'"
/...some-path.../lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:38:in `require': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

This error persist regardless of the version of ruby that I'm using (2.1, 2.3), so I'm guessing it's a config entry common to both, but I don't know where to start looking at.

Comment: Works for me. I suspect you have some wrapper around `ruby` which is causing issues?

Comment: All three work for me on linux

Comment: All 3 work for me, ubuntu 16.04/ruby 2.3.3p222, and windows 7/ruby 2.2.3p173

Comment: They work perfectly fine for me running irb, but as soon as I try to use them from the command line, they just give me this behavior. I have no idea where to start looking for the root-cause.

Comment: I find it unfair to be down-voted when I'm making a question about: "this is the behaviour that I'm seeing, What should I look for?"

Comment: Have you checked for any aliases for ruby? Do other commands like awk have a similar issue?  Why double quotes around script and not single? You can also use -r switch to include a library.

Comment: `which ruby` points me to my binary. Changed the quotes to all double (escaped), and also switched them both with the same results. Tested with awk and it does behave as expected (whitespaces not an issue). I'm doing an strace at this point but I'm not finding anything valuable.

Comment: `strace` is telling me that it's actually using a wrapper. I think I know now where to look next. I appreciate your help.